# addClass to div on change of dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following dropdown:

```
<select name="about_performance_lead_singer" id="about_performance_lead_singer" value="">
    <option value="Toni">Toni</option>
    <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="James">James</option>        
</select>
```

Below this I have the following divs:

```
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="toni">...</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="jack">...</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="james">...</div>
```

These are set to display:none using css

I'm trying to make it so when I select the name from the dropdown, the class "visible" is added to the corresponding div - and then removed again if the selection is changed again.

Here is what I have tried so far, but with no luck:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$("#about_performance_lead_singer").change(function () {
       $('#'(this).val()).addClass('visible');  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You also need to convert the value to `lowerCase()` to get the exact match.

```
<select name="about_performance_lead_singer" id="about_performance_lead_singer" value="">
    <option value="Toni">Toni</option>
    <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="James">James</option>        
</select>

<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="toni">toni</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="jack">jack</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="james">james</div>

<style>
.singer_profile_overview
{
    display:none;
}

.visible
{
    display: block
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$("#about_performance_lead_singer").change(function () {
    $('.singer_profile_overview').removeClass('visible'); // hide all divs by removing class visible
       $('#' + $(this).val().toLowerCase()).addClass('visible');  // find the matching div and add class visible to it
    });
});

</script>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/204/

Comment: This is great, how do I get them to change back to display:none if user changes selection again?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do this:

html:

```
<select name="about_performance_lead_singer" id="about_performance_lead_singer" value="">
    <option value="nothing">Select One</option>
    <option value="Toni">Toni</option>
    <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="James">James</option>        
</select>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="Toni">toni</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="Jack">jack</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="James">james</div>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$("#about_performance_lead_singer").change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);   
    $('.singer_profile_overview').removeClass('visible');
    $('#' + $this.val()).addClass('visible');  
    });
});
```

Couple of notes:

- It is a good practice to store `$(this)` in a local variable, I usually call it `$this`.
- You had an upper case / lower case problem in your original code. The `id` of the class to update needs to match the id you call in your selector
- Remove the `visible` class from every `<div>` prior to applying one.
- And there is still one problem, if you click your dropdown and select the first option, the event will not fire because nothing changed. That is why I added a 'Select One' option.

And here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy1yy748/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:selected` selector to find the option that was selected. We can get its value by calling the `prop` method and passing in `value` as an attribute. Since the ids we are trying to get are lowercase, we use the `toLowerCase()` method.

The div we're trying to get is of the class `.singer_profile_overview`. We should use the `filter` function to get the ids. We store the result of this filter in a jQuery variable and finally add a class to it.

```js
$("#about_performance_lead_singer").change(function () {
       var selectedValue = $(":selected").prop("value").toLowerCase();
       var selectedDiv = $(".singer_profile_overview").filter(function() {
           return $(this).prop("id") == selectedValue;
       });
       selectedDiv.addClass('visible');  
    });
```

```css
.visible {
    color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="about_performance_lead_singer" id="about_performance_lead_singer" value="">
    <option value="Toni">Toni</option>
    <option value="Jack">Jack</option>
    <option value="James">James</option>        
</select>

<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="toni">Toni</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="jack">Jack</div>
<div class="singer_profile_overview" id="james">James</div>
```

Comment: How would this add the class to the corresponding div though?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the value of the dropdown are capitalized, while your `id`s are lowercase. Consider the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$("#about_performance_lead_singer").change(function () {
       $('#'(this).val().toLowerCase()).addClass('visible');  
    });
});
```

Or alternatively, you can manually change the values to lower case, or the `id`s to be capitalized to match the values.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as it was asked:

```
$("#about_performance_lead_singer").on("change", function(){
    $(".singer_profile_overview").removeClass("visible");
    $("#" + $(this).val().toLowerCase()).addClass("visible");
});
```

However, if you're only using the class "visible" to toggle their display, you can replace

```
removeClass("visible")
```

with

```
hide()
```

and

```
addClass("visible")
```

with

```
show()
```